# Uploading PDF with a POST request to an API in Python

Tags: python, api, pdf, python-requests

I'm trying to upload a PDF file using `requests.post` in Python but the uploaded PDF file isn't correct. It has the right number of pages but the content is blank. Using the following code:

```py
import json
import requests
import codecs
import os
import base64

token = 'api token'
url = 'api url'

pdf_file = "testdoc.pdf"
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
attachments_path = dir_path + '/' + pdf_file

# decode pdf and store in string
pdf = codecs.open(str(attachments_path), encoding="ISO8859")
pdf = str(pdf.read())
    
attachments = [{"name": "testdocument.pdf","contentType": "application/pdf","contentBytes": pdf}]

content = 'test'
payload = {
            "content": content,
            "attachments": attachments
}
headers = {
            'apiToken': token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

I've also tried the following for decoding the pdf file:

```py
with open(str(attachments_path), 'rb') as f:
    pdf = base64.encodebytes(f.read()).decode('utf-8')
```

but in this case, the uploaded pdf file is corrupted and does not open. How do I make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing `.decode('utf-8')` at the end.

Comment: @TheMaster Still doesn't work, the uploaded PDF has a pdf extension but when I open it in a text editor it's just a long number/character string (not sure what this is called), this is the first line for example `JVBERi0xLjcNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFu`

Comment: You should decode it(`base64.decodebytes()`) serverside. The idea is to b64 encode(urlsafe if needed) it client side, send the encoded string,c decode it serverside.